# String interpolation with constants

Tags: php, string-interpolation

How could I make string interpolation with constants?

I tried with this code but it seems it not working:

```
class DB{

    const DBNAME = "test";
    private $host = "localhost";

    public function __construct(){
        $connectionString = "dbname={DB::DBNAME}";     //with will not work
        $connectionString = "host={$this->host}";      //no problem with this
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do string interpolation with constants?

Comment: @apokryfos I don't think this is duplicate

Comment: Why not, you ask if there's a way to interpolate a constant in a string, the answer (as shown in that question) is no there isn't

Comment: OK then , your comment is enough answer to me , thanks